# Публичные свойства с#

Tags: c#, классы

Нужно Tc , T , names объявить свойствами класса (публичным)

```
public class laba2
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            static void TR(double[] Tc, double T, string[] names)
            {
                for (int i=0; i<Tc.Length; i++)
                {
                    double Tr = T / Tc[i];
                    Console.Write("{1}: {0:0.0000}  ", Tr, names[i]);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("\n");
            }
            
            double[] Tc = new double[3] {132.9, 304.2, 190.6};
            string[] names = new string[] {"CO", "CO2", "CH4"};
    
            string updatetime = "";
            for (double t = 100; t <= 200; t += 2.5)
            {
                double T = t + 273.15;
                TR(Tc, T, names);
                DateTime localDate = DateTime.Now;
                updatetime = localDate.ToString();
            }
    
            string Version = "1.0.1";
            Console.WriteLine("Версия: {1}, Время последних измений: {0}", updatetime, Version);
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: А в чем тут проблема? Как вы пробовали? Не уж то у вас возникли трудности с написанием `public double T {get; private set;}` и использования его?

Comment: Я хотел уточнить, как это будет выглядеть, так как думаю, что для каждого параметра придётся прописывать свойства public

Comment: Выглядеть что? Вот у вас есть класс, должен ли другой класс, который использует ваш, иметь доступ к его внутренностям? К его свойствам, методам? Если нет - приватный, если да - публичный. Делать все публичным, сами понимаете - бред. Как сделать свойство - я вам сказал выше. Так что извините, я не понимаю ваш вопрос, вообще...

Answer (score 1):

Объявите эти переменные в классе, а не в методе. С модификатороми public и static. У вас возникла проблема из-за того что метод Main статичный.